# Invalid credentials on puppet install of openldap

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, openldap

I'm having problems getting puppet to install a working openldap server using the following:

- Vagrant 1.2.2
- Ubuntu 12 ([Puppetlabs Ubuntu 12.04.2 x86_64](http://puppet-vagrant-boxes.puppetlabs.com/ubuntu-server-12042-x64-vbox4210.box))
- [torian/ldap 0.2.4](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/torian/ldap)

I have the torian/ldap module in my vagrant folder and the following in the base puppet file:

```
class { 'ldap::server::master':
  suffix      => 'dc=example,dc=co,dc=uk',
  rootpw      => 'adminadmin';
}
```

`vagrant up` starts the VM without any errors and openldap is running on port 389. As I understand it the root user should default to:

```
cn=admin,dc=example,dc=co,dc=uk
```

but if I try to connect with the above user/password either remotely or using:

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=co,dc=uk" -W
```

I get an `Invalid Credentials` error. I've also tried with the same password SHA encoded:

```
rootpw      => '{SHA}3ZRwlSi7HIPQjzCI1AQ/R0KJH08=';
```

but no luck. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

**Update**

Running `slapcat -f /usr/share/slapd/slapd.conf` shows these two entries:

```
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=nodomain
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9R2lES2JuRERqYU1rNGROSG5rN1hTa3dteEdOVjBlYmU=
```

Those are clearly different to the ones passed to the puppet module.

**Almost there...**

Thanks to emsworth for pointing me in the right direction it's nearly working. It's copying an LDIF update file over and trying to run ldapmodify on it to modify the root DN and password, but this seems to corrupt things. Before the ldapmodify the slapd service starts ok, afterwards trying to restart slapd fails. The update file is:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com
-
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
-
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SHA}3ZRwlSi7HIPQjzCI1AQ/R0KJH08=
-
```

and it's being run with the following command:

```
/usr/bin/ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f
  /etc/ldap/slapd.conf/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}hdb-update.ldif
```

Trying to run the update manually as root with the above command gives the error:

```
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
```

and in syslog:

```
Jan  6 15:31:15 ubuntu-server-12042-x64-vbox4210 slapd[19166]: ldif_write_entry:
cannot create file for "olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config": Permission denied
```

Comment: Which version of openldap are you using?

Comment: It has installed openldap-2.4.28

Comment: Do you know if you are using the OLC (dynamic) configuration or the legacy configuration?  I can set the admin user and password in: /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif, but I'm using the dynamic config.

Comment: I have a '/etc/ldap/slapd.conf/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}hdb.ldif' file that contains the user/password mentioned in the update (cn=admin,cn=nodomain). I expect I could modify those, but really I want the puppet module to set them properly.

Comment: My guess is that you are running into a limitation of the ldap puppet module: https://github.com/torian/puppet-ldap/pull/18, specifically with regard to the dynamic config vs slapd.conf config.

Comment: Does the dn in the update script exist?  What happens if you just use dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb in that update script?

Comment: Also, did you try running slapd manually with debugging output turned on?  What error is slapd giving on startup?

Comment: With just 'olcDatabase={1}hdb' I get the error 'ldap_modify: Server is unwilling to perform (53) additional info: no global superior knowledge'

Comment: Tried 'slapd -d 1' (is that right?). Only message that looks like an error is 'regular file expected, got "/etc/ldap/slapd.conf"'.

Comment: On second glance, the update script looks OK.  The debug output options can be found via 'slapd -d?'.  I'm out of ideas for now, but I'll update if I think of something else.

Comment: One other thing - I find that things like SELinux can cause screwy results with openldap, so make sure that is turned off, at least to debug the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are running into a limitation with the puppet module (see comments to your original question).  You could try modifying your ldap instance to use the old style configuration, create a separate puppet directive to replace the olc file, or even try patching the module (there is a patch that supposedly will properly handle the newer configuration on github).

Comment: The patch didn't work as it was, issues with paths etc., but after working through the problems it's almost there, just one issue left with ldapmodify. I'll update the question with that...

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you add a `rootdn` directive to your class definition?

```
class { 'ldap::server::master':
  suffix      => 'dc=example,dc=co,dc=uk',
  rootdn      => 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=co,dc=uk',
  rootpw      => 'adminadmin',
}
```

I don't know about this particular class, but I know that OpenLDAP OOTB doesn't necessarily set the root DN.